# Selecting items from List-box in Scheme

Tags: user-interface, scheme, racket

There is a list-box which has three columns. I'm trying to get all the row of a index (item) which are selected.

The problem is that i can't get the whole row. The following function returns just the value of the row in first column, not values in other columns:

```
 (send my-list-box get-string-selection)
```

And this is my-list-box

```
(define my-list-box (new list-box%
                      (label "")
                      (parent third-layer)
                      (choices '("First" "Second") )
                      (style (list 'multiple
                                   'variable-columns
                                   'column-headers))
                      (columns (list "URL of Source" "Redirection Url" "Authentication Code" ))))
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you call `(send my-list-box get-selections)`? I tried it and it worked for me.

It looks like there's no way to get the label (string) from a column other than the first column. You can only set it. But you can associate extra data with each row using the `set-data` method. So you might want to set the data to be a list of all of the column values, for example.

Comment: I didn't understand what was wrong but now 'get-selections' worked also for me. i have updated my question. But still the question about selecting the whole row is not answered. There is probably no explicit method to get it but is there no other way to get it or is 'setdata' the only alternative?

Comment: @Asqan, I looked at some of the code that implements `list-box%`, and I'm pretty sure there's no other way to get the other label strings in the row.